# TypeError: Object.keys: el argumento no es un objeto

Tags: javascript

Estoy probando la compatibilidad con navegadores y en IE11 me esta dando este error y firefox,chrome,etc funciona

```
 if (array && Object.keys(array).length > 0) {
        ..............
 }
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Object.keys: el argumento no es un objeto
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917961/object-keys-behavior-in-chrome-and-ie-11 mira este enlace te puede ayudar

Comment: Si el objeto que pasas como argumento no es un objeto primitivo (veo que te refieres al mismo como *array*) es posible que lance el error que te está dando. Esto es porque si bien, IE11 acepta dicha función, no hace la coerción de *Array* a *Objeto*. Esto posiblemente se deba a un tema de compatibilidad con el estándar ES2015. Tomado de la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys). Saludos

Comment: Aquí la parte interesante: *En ES5, si el argumento para este método no es un objeto (uno primitivo), causará un TypeError. En ES2015, un argumento no-objeto será coaccionado hacia un objeto.*

Answer (score 1):

Según [RobG de StackOverflow, en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917961/object-keys-behavior-in-chrome-and-ie-11#answer-31919087), este es un problema relacionado con IE que implementa el método Object.keys utilizando estándares JS antiguos.

Anule la definición de Object.keys del navegador con

```js
Object.keys = function(obj) {
    var keys = [];

    for (var i in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        keys.push(i);
      }
    }

    return keys;
  };
```